# Disabling a button in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton

I need to disable a button if the key does not exist in the dictionary. I have used the setEnabled functionality of the UIButton but the image that has been set default still appears.

The code looks like this:

```
if([self.InfoDictionary objectForKey:ButtonExist])
{
    [button1 setEnabled:YES];
}
else
{
    [button1 setEnabled:NO];
}
```

The image still appears when I run in the simulator. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: `enabled` controls whether the button does anything.  You can use `hidden` to make it invisible, or set `alpha` between `0.0` and `1.0` to make it look greyed out.

Comment: what is ButtonExist? is this key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`enable = YES` property of button performs the action when clicked.

`enable = NO` property prevents action to be executed on click.

If you want to hide the button then you can set the `hidden` property as `YES` or vice versa. Other way to hide is by setting the `alpha` property to `0` (invisible) or `1` (visible)

Answer (score 7):

Also you can set `userInteractionEnabled` property of `UIButton`

```
 if([self.InfoDictionary objectForKey:ButtonExist])
    {
        [button1 setEnabled:YES];
        button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [button1 setEnabled:NO];
        button1.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's issue that the images still appear.

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
if([self.InfoDictionary objectForKey:ButtonExist])
{
    [button1 setHidden:YES];
}
else
{
    [button1 setHidden:NO];
}
```

if you want to hide UIImage of UIButton then:

```
if([self.InfoDictionary objectForKey:ButtonExist])
    {
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Hope this will help you.
All the best !!!

Comment: UIButton is a UIView subclass.

Answer (score 1):

in swift3:

```
self.button.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself. The problem was that I was inadvertently enabling the button in a gesture handler for tap!

Look for side effects like this.